# MS SQL Server: Create a sequence based on a column's value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

Table: **Cities**

```
  City      NumberOfSchools
 ------------------------------
  SCL           3
  Blah          5
  Narf          2
          ....
```

What query can I use (being TransactSQL or not) to create a table X?

Table: **X**

```
  City      Sequence
 ------------------------------
  SCL           1
  SCL           2
  SCL           3
  Blah          1
  Blah          2
  Blah          3
  Blah          4
  Blah          5
  Narf          1
  Narf          2
          ....
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: How can I include attempted solutions if I don't know how to do this in pure SQL (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE)? I know how to do this using a  language like Java or C#, using cycles such as while, for, etc.

Comment: The point of this web site is that if you're asking for code, you show a minimum effort.

Comment: And I did, by creating the asked table using other languages, but that doesn't need to be known by the users answering the question. In fact, putting all that "effort" here would distort the question and add noise to it. You should focus more on the question itself and not in evaluating if the user is a hardworking person.

Comment: The minimum effort here is an attempt at writing a query. Please take a few moments to read over the site's [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT A.City, B.number Sequence
FROM Cities A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT *
            FROM master.dbo.spt_values
            WHERE type = 'P'
            AND number > 0) B
WHERE B.number <= A.NumberOfSchools
```

[**Here is an sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21d93/1) for you to try.

Comment: Three cheers for Numbers tables!